# Proving that, $|f'(x)-f'(y)|\le k|x-y| \implies (f'(x))^2< 2 kf(x) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f:\Bbb R\to (0,\infty)$ be a differentiable function such that for some constant $k$ we have, $$|f'(x)-f'(y)|\le k|x-y|$$
>   for all $x,y \in\Bbb R.$ Then prove that, $$(f'(x))^2<2 kf(x).$$

Due to lack of arguments I could not proof this inequality. But rather I proved that is true for the particular function,

$$f(x) =\cos^2(x)+1\implies f'(x) = -\sin(2x).$$
And we readily have,$$|\sin(2x)-\sin(2y)| = \left|\int_{2x}^{2y}\cos t dt\right|\le 2|x-y|$$ as well

$$(f'(x))^2 = 4 \sin^2 x\cos^2x < 4(\cos^2x +1) = 4f(x).$$

It is also true for the function $x\mapsto \sin^2x +1.$

From these example I don't see how to prove the general case. Any hint will be welcome.

Comment: What a question? it does not look trivial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix $x \in \Bbb R$.

$f'$ is (Lipschitz) continuous and therefore integrable.
For any $d \ge 0$ we have
$$
0 < f(x+d) = f(x) + \int_x^{x+d} f'(t) \, dt
= f(x) + df'(x) + \int_x^{x+d}(f'(t) - f'(x)) \, dt \\
\le f(x) + df'(x) + \int_x^{x+d}k(t-x) \, dt \\
= f(x) + df'(x) + \frac 12 kd^2 
$$
and the same estimate holds for $d < 0$, because then
$$
 \int_x^{x+d}(f'(t) - f'(x)) \, dt = -\int_{x+d}^x(f'(t) - f'(x)) \, dt
 \le -\int_{x+d}^x k(t-x) \, dt = \frac 12 k d^2 \, .
$$

In particular for $d = -\frac{f'(x)}{k}$ we get
$$
 0 < f(x) - \frac{f'(x)^2}{k} + \frac{f'(x)^2}{2k}
 = f(x) - \frac{f'(x)^2}{2k}
$$
which is the desired conclusion.

Comment: You might consider explaining why we can assume that $f'(x)<0$. Took me a minute to see this in my version...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I have reformulated it such that the assumption is not needed anymore. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: can u pls tell me how did u wrte 3rd line. After fundamental theorem of integral calculus?pls clarify

Comment: @MartinR can u pls elaborate? i am novice and learning things. can u pls tell me how did u wrte 3rd line. After fundamental theorem of integral calculus?pls clarify

Comment: @anirudhb: $\int_x^{x+d}(f'(t) - f'(x)) \, dt \le \int_x^{x+d}|f'(t) - f'(x)| \, dt \le \int_x^{x+d}k(t-x) \, dt = k \int_0^d u \, du = \frac 12 kd^2 $.

Comment: @MartinR i am not able to type integral in latex. I am asking 3rd line 

... = 2nd term = 3rd term(how 3rd term is obtained from 2nd)

f(x)+∫x+dxf′(t)dt=f(x)+df′(x)+∫x+dx(f′(t)−f′(x))dt

Comment: @anirudhb: Substitute $f'(t)$ by $f'(x) + (f'(t) - f'(x))$ inside the integral.

Comment: got it @MartinR thnx a lot

Comment: Why is the first inequality strict?

Comment: @GuyFsone: You assumed that  $f:\Bbb R\to (0,\infty)$, so $f(x+d) > 0$.

Comment: Yes I got it thanks:)

Answer (score 4):

This is reminiscent of [Landau's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_inequality).

WLOG $k=1$ (consider $g=f/k$).

Suppose $f'(0)^2 \ge 2f(0)$. WLOG $f'(0) \le -(2f(0))^{1/2}$ (if otoh $f'(0)$ is positive consider $g(t)=f(-t)$.) Then for every $t>0$ we have
$$f'(t)\le t-(2f(0))^{1/2}.$$Integrating, this shows that $$f(x)\le f(0)+x^2/2-2x(2f(0))^{1/2}$$for every $x>0$. If $x=(8f(0))^{1/2}$ it follows that $f(x)<0$.

So $f'(0)^2<2f(0)$. The general case follows ((let $g(t)=f(x+t)$.)

Comment: this is a Good answer but very compact.  for me:)

Comment: @GuyFsone If there's a step you don't get I can explain.